# Python 3.6: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when trying to print all links in a page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm attending an online course on Python for beginners. The course explained how to print all links in web page source code. I wrote the codes for doing this using Notepad++, and then pasted them into the Python interpreter (Python 3.6 on Windows).

```
def get_next_target(page):
    start_link=page.find('<a href=')
    if start_link==-1:
        return None,0
    start_quote=page.find('"',start_link)
    end_quote=page.find('"',start_quote+1)
    url=page[start_quote+1,end_quote]
    return url,end_quote

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url,endpos=(get_next_target(page))
        if url:
            print(url)
            page=page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

def get_page(url):
    import urllib.request
    return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

print_all_links(get_page('https://youtube.com'))
```

After I hit Enter, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print_all_links
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_next_target
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my codes.

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at python (auto-)formatting: autopep8 or yapt, for example, and linting.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thank you for reminding. I actually cannot decide which answer to accept. Your answer and grovina's answer are both helpful to me in different respects. So I decide to leave the question unanswered. I do have voted for the answers of both of you, though I have not enough reputations yet to make my vote count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug arises because you call `urlopen.read` which returns a `bytes` object. You're then attempting to search this bytestring with *`str`* search strings, which causes the error.

Luckily, the fix is really small. Call `bytes.decode` to convert the `bytes` to an `str` object.

```
import urllib.request

def get_page(url):    
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return url.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Also, I'd recommend importing all required modules *once*, at the top of your script.

Comment: Also, as the other answer mentions, you probably want `page[start_quote+1:end_quote]` with the `:` colon, not `,` comma.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to decode the `read()` output:

```
return urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Also, you have a small typo in the following line (`,` where you probably meant `:`):

```
url = page[start_quote+1:end_quote]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using requests package instead of urllib. You can refer to the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://douban.com"
r  = requests.get(url) 
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   print link.get("href")
```